# Что-то напоминающее - запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

### Что-то (?) напоминающее

Чем можно объяснить отсутствие или наличие запятой на месте вопросительного знака?

В Нацкропусе, например, встречаются варианты как с, так и без пунктуационного знака.

"Это были самодельные, сделанные из куска домашней кожи даже не сапоги, не тапки, а что-то напоминающее индейские мокасины".[Юрий Сенкевич. "Путешествие длиною в жизнь(1999)]

"Зато, когда начало получаться что-то, напоминающее движения настоящих танцоров «электрик-буги», душу охватывала спортивная гордость".[Алексей Козлов. "Козёл на саксе(1998)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Наличие вариантов в этом случае объясняется у Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

3. **Определительный оборот, стоящий после неопределённого местоимения, обычно не обособляется**, так как образует единое целое с предшествующим местоимением: Её большие глаза… искали в моих что-нибудь похожее на надежду (Л.); В нём уснули все желания, кроме желания думать о чём-то невыразимом словами (М. Г.); На лице его промелькнуло нечто похожее на усмешку.

**Но при менее тесной связи слов и при наличии после местоимения паузы оборот обособляется** (выделяется запятыми): И кто-то, вспотевший и задыхающийся, бегает из магазина в магазин (Пан.) — обособлены два одиночных определения.

2) Объяснение примеров:

*Это были самодельные, сделанные из куска домашней кожи даже не сапоги, не тапки, а **что-то напоминающее индейские мокасИны.***

Нет паузы и нет ударения на местоимении, тесная связь неопределенного местоимения и причастного оборота.

*Зато когда начало получаться **чтО-то, напоминающее движения настоящих танцоров «электрик-буги»**, душу охватывала спортивная гордость.*

Пауза, нет тесной связи, ударение падает на местоимение.
Сравнить: *Потом стало что-то получаться.* Или: *Стало что-то по-настоящему получаться ― после этого захотелось играть сильней и сильней.*

Местоимение *что-то* в этих примерах **употребляется без определительного оборота**, оно более самостоятельное, поэтому оборот можно обособить.

Comment: Спасибо! Типичный пример добротного ответа по сравнению с поверхностным.

Answer (score 1):

Считаете, что здесь причастный оборот, относящийся к слову "что-то"? Попробуйте его убрать. Что станет с предложением? Смысл исчезнет. "Что-то напоминающее" - это неразрывное сочетание, нельзя его разбивать.

Пунктуация второй фразы сомнительна, ее не стоит рассматривать всерьез, поскольку там есть и еще одна ошибка - запятая после "зато".